# Why the imfilter give different result with textbook?

Tags: matlab, image-processing

As the textbook say,this code

```
w=ones(31);
gd=imfilter(f,w)
```

will give a result with blurry edge like follow

[image]

But actually I will get a result :

```
w=ones(31);
gd=imfilter(f,w);
imshow(gd)
```

[image]

This is [original picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PIlSu.png).Maybe I have missed something.

Comment: When was your book written? Which Matlab version are you using?

Comment: What is `f`? ‍‍‍‍‍‍ ‍‍Are you sure it is same in that book and what you have?

Comment: @LeanderMoesinger *Digtal Image Processing Using Matlab 2nd*

Comment: @SardarUsama It is image data of original picture.

Comment: @SardarUsama,LeanderMoesinger I know the reason,I should use `31^2` to divide the `w`

Comment: @yode The text says "We did not divide the coefficients by (31)^2..." If that doesn't relate to the figures (it's hard to tell from just the text you've posted), then yes you would normally divide by the number of elements to get an averaging filter.